# How to efficiently update part of a mongodb record?

Tags: database, mongodb

In mongodb, if I have a user record like this

```
{
    _id:1,
    name:"John",
    items : [
        {wid:1, type:"basic"},
        {wid:1, type:"rare"}
    ]
}
```

And I want to update the name of `rare` to `uncommon`. How can I efficiently do it? My concern is if that array was 1 million length, do I need to push that huge array (which includes the new update somewhere in it) in the update call when I add, update or delete something from it? Is there a way I can be more efficient only push the delta change?

Thanks

Comment: You can try $ the positional update operator or array filters.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the name of rare to uncommon

You can do that. In your example, you can pass `type:rare` in the condition and use `arrayFilters` to update.

[Bulk find with arrayfilters to update only what needs to be updated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/)

[Refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.collection.update(
   { <query selector> },
   { <update operator>: { "array.$[<identifier>].field" : value } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { <identifier>: <condition> } } ] }
)
```

> do I need to push that huge array (which includes the new update somewhere in it) in the update call when I add, update or delete something from it?

Not necessarily. You can update as mentioned above.

You can add easily using `$push`.

You can delete using `$pull`.